# Instantiating classes in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

the last couple of weeks i have been working on my own WordPress plugin. I am trying to do a class based codebase.

My plugin works correctly, but i don't really know if this is the correct way to develop. I would like to learn the best practices.

To demonstrate, here is my base plugin file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Blub Hamerhaai plugin
 *
 * This is the main blub plugin for all sites
 *
 * @link              {github link}
 * @since             0.0.2
 * @package           Blub Hamerhaai
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:       {plugin name}
 * Plugin URI:        {github link}
 * Description:       This is the main blub plugin for all sites
 * Version:           0.0.4
 * Author:            Blub
 * Author URI:        {link}
 * License:           Copyright Blub media, all rights reserved
 * License URI:       {link}
 * Text Domain:       blub-hamerhaai
 * Domain Path:       /languages
 *
 * Created by:        Me
 */

namespace Blub;

require 'includes/includes.php';

define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\PLUGINROOT', __FILE__);
define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\PLUGINDIR', __DIR__);

if (!class_exists('Hamerhaai')) {
    class Hamerhaai
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            register_activation_hook(__FILE__, [$this, 'activation']);
            register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, [$this, 'deactivation']);
            add_action('init', [$this, 'init']);
        }

        public function activation()
        {
            BlubRole::add();
            PluginUpdate::add();
        }

        public function deactivation()
        {
            BlubRole::remove();
            PluginUpdate::remove();
        }

        public function init()
        {
            //Preventing removals in other pages
            global $pagenow;

            load_textdomain('blub-hamerhaai', PLUGINDIR . '/languages/blub-hamerhaai-nl_NL.mo');

            //Things to do for all users
            new OptionsPage();
            new BlubColors();
            new CustomLoginPage();
            $widget = new DashboardWidget();

            // Things to do for blub user
            if (BlubRole::isBlubUser()) {
                new AdminText();
                new RemoveMenuItems();
                new GutenbergEdits();

                //Only for dashboard
                if ($pagenow === 'index.php') {
                    $widget->forceShow();
                    $widget->removeDefault();
                }

                new LoadFrontendStyle();
            }
        }
    }
}

new Hamerhaai();
```

The main thing i am insecure about is instantiating all the classes on the plugin init function. I don't think this is the best practice. All the classes are based on a specific functionality.

Can someone explain me if this is the way to go? Or how to improve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. The constructor is not a good place for actions & filters.**

See [this very detailed answer from WP.SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/164121/testing-hooks-callback/164138#164138) or [this blog post](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-plugin-constructors-hooks/) for some reasoning. As far as I understand, it makes testing much more difficult and in a oop-way doesn't make sense, as it doesn't directly relate to the object's state.

**2. Do you really need that state?**

Right now, your `Hamerhaai` doesn't actually use state. In this case I usually define the methods as static, which makes enqueue/dequeue much simpler because you don't need the original object.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, [$this, 'activation']);

// ...
public function activation()
{
    BlubRole::add();
    PluginUpdate::add();
}
```

would become

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, [__CLASS__, 'activation']);

// ...
public static function activation()
{
    BlubRole::add();
    PluginUpdate::add();
}
```

(using `__CLASS__` simplifies it a lot so you don't need to watch out for namespaces, see [PHP Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#71064))

**3. Don't go half the way.**

You're doing modern PHP code. So why `require 'includes/includes.php';`? Use [composer's autoloading](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-autoload-classes-with-composer-in-php--cms-35649) feature and avoid manual `include` / `require` statements. In my plugins, all code lives somewhere in a class. And the class is easily autoloaded via composer.

You're in a namespace, so `if (!class_exists('Hamerhaai')) {`  doesn't actually do what you think it does. Instead you should either check for `if (!class_exists('Blub\Hamerhaai')) {` or as you're already using `__NAMESPACE__` something like

```
if (!class_exists(__NAMESPACE__ . '\Hamerhaai')) {
```

**4. Only load code that is actually required**

```
        //Things to do for all users
        new OptionsPage();
        new BlubColors();
        new CustomLoginPage();
        $widget = new DashboardWidget();
```

this code lives in your `init()` method. So it is called on every request. Most likely you want to check if the user is logged in, has a specific role, etc. before actually calling it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!